# Custom function to rename all columns

Tags: r, function

I want to manipulate the names of all the columns in a dataframe with this function that I wrote:

```
clean_names <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\s', '\\_', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\(|\\)|\\/|,|\\.', '\\_', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('(\\_)\\_', '\\1', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\_$', '', names(df))
}
```

That said, when actually called, it doesn't do anything (no error just nothing).
What's the problem here?

I suspect the problem is that I'm only assigning things and not returning anything. But in this case I don't want to return a value just change the column names.

The only parameter here is `df` and I'm calling the `names()` function multiple times. Shouldn't this work? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't return anything. Add a line with just `df` before your close brace.

Comment: Your function is correct. its just that you are not printing anything at the end. To see the results, do `(clean_names(your_df))` Note that I have extra paranthesis around the command. That is to explicitly print. Or you could do `print(clean_names(df))` Lastly you could do an assignment. ie `new_df <- clean_names(your_df)` and now check `new_df`

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu the assignment at the end fixed the issue. I thought the function itself would have the desired side effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here:

1. R tends to ***not*** operate in side-effect, so while you may pass a `data.frame` in to it, the first time you change anything about it, the `df` in the function is completely copied into a new object that will go away when the function is done. The original frame is untouched. There are some functions in R that operate in side-effect, but most of R is not. With this, you cannot just make changes *inside* the function and assume that it will have an effect *outside* of the function. For this, you would need to reassign the results back to the frame, as in:

   ```r
   mydata <- clean_names(mydata)
   ```
2. When there is no literal `return(.)` statement in a function, R will return the last expression (often invisibly). You will often see functions end with the desired object (`df` here) without using the literal `return` function; that function is useful in some circumstances but usually not needed.

   The last expression is usually *invisible*. You can see what is really happening by capturing the return value in a new variable or, as a shortcut, just `(clean_names(mydata))`. My gut feeling is that the output from that function is a vector of strings.

   Why? Because the last expression is a reassignment of names. The RHS of that assignment is producing a `character` vector, and that is passed to the `` `names<-` `` function on the LHS, and that value (the vector of strings) is then used as the return value of the function.

   The resolution here is to add `df` (or `return(df)` if you must) to the end of your function, as in:

   ```r
   clean_names <- function(df) {
     names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
     names(df) <- gsub('\\s', '\\_', names(df))
     names(df) <- gsub('\\(|\\)|\\/|,|\\.', '\\_', names(df))
     names(df) <- gsub('(\\_)\\_', '\\1', names(df))
     names(df) <- gsub('\\_$', '', names(df))
     df
   }
   ```

After doing *both* of those steps, you should then get data.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Point 1 fixed the issue and cleared the confusion! I was under the naive impression that the function will automatically have the desired side effect

Answer (score 2):

From the `names` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/names):

> For names<-, the updated object. (Note that the value of names(x) <- value is that of the assignment, value, not the return value from the left-hand side.)

Therefore you should try:

```
clean_names <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\s', '\\_', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\(|\\)|\\/|,|\\.', '\\_', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('(\\_)\\_', '\\1', names(df))
  names(df) <- gsub('\\_$', '', names(df))
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @r2evans! May I ask in what occasion is the use of `return` necessary in a function?

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve anything. Maybe I didn't explain the problem well, my bad. I don't want to return the df. I just want to change (i.e., clean) the already existing column names of a dataframe

Comment: Only if you need to exit the function with a value to interrupt code that remains after your point.